# Regex for only numbers and numbers including slash

Tags: php, regex

I want regex for following possibilities:

```
01212
111/11
12121221/23445

[0-9]
[0-9]/[1-9]
```

I am trying `([0-9]|[\/]|[1-9])` and it is working except for zero after slash.
I don't want `1212/0`

PS: I am new to regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^0*[1-9]\d*(?:/0*[1-9]\d*)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/44qDLF/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `0*`: Match 0 or more zeroes
- `[1-9]`: Match a non-zero digit
- `\d*`: Match 0 more of any digit
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `/`: Match a `/`
  - `0*[1-9]\d*`: Match a number not containing all zeroes
- `)?`: End non-capture group. `?` makes it an optional match
- `$`: End